# Using lambda expressions with non-functional interfaces in Java

Tags: java, android, lambda, java-8

I have a bunch of animation listeners in my code where only one method in the interface used the majority of the time.

So I created this wrapper:

```
public class AnimationWrapper {
    private Animation mAnimation;

    public AnimationWrapper(Animation animation) {
        mAnimation = animation;
    }

    public Animation getAnimation() {
        return mAnimation;
    }

    public interface OnAnimationEnd {
        void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation);
    }

    public interface OnAnimationStart {
        void onAnimationStart(Animation animation);
    }

    public void setAnimationEndListener(OnAnimationEnd listener) {
        mAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                listener.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void setAnimationStartListener(OnAnimationStart listener) {
        mAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                listener.onAnimationStart(animation);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

That way code like this:

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.my_animation);

animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        doSomething();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
});
```

Ends looking like this:

```
    AnimationWrapper wrapper = new AnimationWrapper(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.my_animation));
    wrapper.setAnimationEndListener(a -> doSomething());
```

I'm just wondering whether there a better way to split non-functional interfaces into separate interfaces with one method, so that each method can be used separately with lambda expressions.

Comment: Is there an abstract AnimationAdapter class which implements empty methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of wrapping the animation, I would wrap the functional, one-method listener into a "real", multi-method listener (i.e. apply the Adapter design pattern):

```
public interface OnAnimationEnd {
    void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation);
}

public interface OnAnimationStart {
    void onAnimationStart(Animation animation);
}

public class AnimationListeners {
    public static Animation.AnimationListener adapt(OnAnimationStart oas) {
        return new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                oas.onAnimationStart(animation);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }
        });
    }

    // same for the end
}
```

And you would just use

```
animation.setAnimationListener(AnimationListeners.adapt(a -> doSomething()));
```

With a static import of the adapt method, it becomes

```
animation.setAnimationListener(adapt(a -> doSomething()));
```

Comment: I needed to use different names for the methods in the adapter because of the compiler complaining they were ambiguous. `adapt(OnAnimationStart oas)`, `adapt(OnAnimationEnd oas)` and such changed to `OnAnimationStartListener(OnAnimationStart oas)`, `OnAnimationEndListener(OnAnimationEnd oas)`.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest applying the builder pattern to construct an `AnimationListener` instance with convenient methods which take `Consumer<Application>`s, keep them into fields, and use these values on the final `build` phase.

There is no need to multiply own interfaces since the `Consumer` already is (and all you might write is three new `Concumer<Animation>` copies).

*I'm not familiar with Android API, so I quickly wrote my own classes. The idea is the same.*

```
class Animation {}

// an analogue of the Animation.AnimationListener class
interface AnimationListener {
    void onAnimationStart(Animation animation);
    void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation);
}

class AnimationListenerBuilder {

    // do nothing by default (avoiding a NPE from the build method)
    private Consumer<Animation> onAnimationStartCallback = animation -> {};
    private Consumer<Animation> onAnimationEndCallback = animation -> {};

    public AnimationListenerBuilder setOnAnimationStartCallback(Consumer<Animation> supplier) {
        onAnimationStartCallback = supplier;
        return this;
    }

    public AnimationListenerBuilder setOnAnimationEndCallback(Consumer<Animation> supplier) {
        onAnimationEndCallback = supplier;
        return this;
    }

    private AnimationListener build() {
        return new AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                onAnimationStartCallback.accept(animation);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                onAnimationEndCallback.accept(animation);
            }

        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AnimationListenerBuilder builder = new AnimationListenerBuilder();

        AnimationListener listener = builder
                .setOnAnimationEndCallback(animation -> {})
                .setOnAnimationEndCallback(animation -> {})
                .build();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`AnimatorListenerAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorListenerAdapter.html). This is an abstract class which implements `Animation.AnimationListener` by providing empty methods. When you extend `AnimatorListenerAdapter`, you only have to implement the methods you want. Such adapters are a common pattern in Java event handling.

Comment: I think it was added in API 11, I need API 8.